# How to use gradients as inputs in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use the gradients of a specific layer of my network as input to the following layer (derivative with respect to the layers weights). My code is too long to put it all here but below is the problematic part (it broke only after inserting it)

```
weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="conv5/weights:0")
deriv = tf.gradients(net, weights)
deriv = tf.squeeze(deriv)
deriv = tf.expand_dims(deriv, 0)
batch_deriv = tf.tile(deriv, [batch_size, 1, 1])
h = tf.reduce_sum(net, axis=1)# maybe normalize ?
new_feature_map = tf.concat([h, batch_deriv], axis=1)
```

I get the following error: (which is in the optimizer and not in my model, but I dont know why)

```
 File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File ".../train.py", line 272, in <module>
    train()
  File ".../train.py", line 133, in train
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=batch)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 315, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 386, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 551, in gradients
    out_grads[i] = control_flow_ops.ZerosLikeOutsideLoop(op, i)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1305, in ZerosLikeOutsideLoop
    pred = op_ctxt.pred
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pred'
```

Anyone know why this happens and how to solve it ?

**UPDATE**

It seems that changing the line

```
new_feature_map = tf.concat([h, batch_deriv], axis=1)
```

to

```
new_feature_map = tf.concat([h, tf.stop_gradient(batch_deriv) ], axis=1)
```

"fixed" it (it dowsnt error anymore), but I have not Idea why. In addition - during evaluation (on the test set) it seems as though the gradients are not computed.

Anyone know how to solve this?